# getting SIGNED samba connection to win10

Tags: samba

required to have *a signed smb connection*.

from https://serverfault.com/questions/680399/how-to-determine-if-a-smb-client-has-established-a-signed-smb-communication-from

using powershell in win10 I do  `Get-SmbConnection | fl *` and it reports `Encrypted : TRUE` but `Signed : False`.

Here is just the global section of my `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file

```
[global]
    workgroup = SAMBA
    security = user

    passdb backend = tdbsam

    printing = bsd
    printcap name = /dev/null
    load printers = no
    disable spoolss = yes
#   cups options = raw


    log level = 0 vfs:10
    log file = /var/log/samba/sambavfs.log
    max log size = 0

    smb encrypt = required
    client min protocol = SMB3
    client max protocol = SMB3

    client ipc signing = mandatory
    client signing = mandatory
    server signing = mandatory
```

can someone tell me what I am missing ?
Want my powershell command to report `signed : true`

this is on

- RHEL 7.9, kernel 3.10.0-1160.36.2.el7.x86_64
- samba-libs-4.10.16-15.el7_9.x86_64
- samba-common-tools-4.10.16-15.el7_9.x86_64
- samba-common-4.10.16-15.el7_9.noarch
- samba-common-libs-4.10.16-15.el7_9.x86_64
- samba-4.10.16-15.el7_9.x86_64
- samba-client-libs-4.10.16-15.el7_9.x86_64

Comment: fwiw - i can comment out `smb encrypt = required` and do `service smb restart`  and that immediately results in `encrypt : false` from powershell command...I can go back and forth from true to false on that so that works.  But the powershell `Signed : False` I can't get to change from false.

Comment: win10 powershell report `Dialect : 3.1.1` which I assume refers to `SMB3` ?

Comment: does SMB3 (versus SMB2 or SMB1) dialect 3.11,do signing by default ?  referring to https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/file-server/file-server-smb-overview